# Strange $.post behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, post

My function works with dynamic (ajax) content and looks like that. I clearly see on firebug that ajax query gets response from serverside. But `$(".playlist-content").html(result);` doesn't happen at all. Furthermore, I placed `alert` to test if function gets there. But neither before nor after `$(".playlist-content").html(result);` alert not happened.

```
$(document).on("click", "#pl-edit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var plid = $(this).data("plid");
    $.post("/playlist/edit", {
        plID: $(this).data("plid"),
        op: "formRetrieve"
    }, function(result) {
        alert("here"); //for testing
        $(".playlist-content").html(result);
        alert("here"); //for testing
    }, "json");
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the `content-type` of the received data?

Comment: It is a wrong content-type. It should be `application/json`. Add header with this content-type. If you are saying that you expect `"json"`. So, what do you want in your response from server? If `html` - remove `,"json"` from function

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, in your function You're using json as content type and your server returns html/text content. Remove `json` from your function and you're good to go.